# Solve ODE by change of variable and separation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have come across the following question:

Solve by change of variable and separation:

$(x+y+1)^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + (x+y+1)^2 + x^3 = 0$

I have tried $u=(x+y+1)^2$, $u=(x+y+1)$ and also $u=\frac{y}{x}$ (thinking it was a homogeneous DE), but haven't been able to get to the separation stage. Am I on the right lines, or have I completely missed the substitution?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your considering $u=x+y+1$ work:

If $x+y+1=0$, then a solution is $y=-x-1$. Else, dividing by $(x+y+1)^2$ gives
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-1-\frac{x^3}{(x+y+1)^2}.$$

Now put $u=x+y+1$, and we have $\frac{du}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}$, thus
$$\frac{du}{dx}-1=-1-\frac{x^3}{u^2}$$
or $$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{x^3}{u^2}$$
therefore
$$\frac{1}{3}u^3=-\frac{1}{4}x^4+c$$
or $$(x+y+1)^3=-\frac{3}{4}x^4+c.$$

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+y+1=v \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}-1$, the ODE becomes
$$v^2(\frac{dv}{dx}-1)+v^2+x^3 \implies v^2\frac{dv}{dx}+x^3=0$$
$$\implies \int v^2 dv+ \int x^3 dx \implies \frac{v^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}=C$$
Hence, $4(x+y+1)^3+3x^3=D$$